# CPPUNIT error: 'Class' does not name a type in test file

Tags: c++, unit-testing, namespaces

I am starting to write unit tests for a program I edit. I did a lot of refactoring and implemented a class with this headerfile:

```
#ifndef GRAPHPRINTER_H
#define GRAPHPRINTER_H

#include "Graph.h"
#include "global.h"
#include "GraphService.h"

using namespace boost;

/*
 * Interface for the GraphPrinter class which provides Graph-related output to
 * the console and to files
 *                           */
class GraphPrinter {

protected:
        //attributes
        Graph g; // a graph
        GraphService service; // a service object to get data from the graph

public:

    //constructors
    GraphPrinter();
    GraphPrinter(const Graph& graph);

    //methods, doing what their name says

    std::string printAdjacent(int i); 
    std::string printAdjacentAll(); 
    void saveGraphStatistics(); // saves the number of vertices and edges and the node-degree-distribution
    void saveAsMatlabVariable(int& number); // saves the graphs as a matlab file
    void saveGraphStatisticsAsMatlabVariable(); // saves the output of printGraphInfo to a matlab file
    void saveInSimpleFormat(); // save the edges of the graph to a file

};

#endif  /* GRAPHPRINTER_H */
```

I want to test the code with unit testing. The  code snippet that worries me is this:

```
#include "newtestclass1.h"
using namespace boost;


CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_REGISTRATION(newtestclass1);

newtestclass1::newtestclass1() {
}

newtestclass1::~newtestclass1() {
}

void newtestclass1::setUp() {

    //defining vertices:
    vi.id = 0;
    ui.id = 1;
    wi.id = 2;

    //defining edges
    ei.source = 0;
    ei.target = 1;

    fi.source = 1;
    fi.target = 2;

    gi.source = 2;
    gi.target = 0;

    //defining graph

    threeNodesGraph[graph_bundle].id = 42;

    v = add_vertex(vi, threeNodesGraph);
    u = add_vertex(ui, threeNodesGraph);
    w = add_vertex(wi, threeNodesGraph);

    add_edge(v,u,ei,threeNodesGraph);
    add_edge(u,w,fi,threeNodesGraph);
    add_edge(w,v,gi,threeNodesGraph);


    // defining the test string and the printer
    testStringAdjacent = "  0:   1  2 ";
    printer = GraphPrinter(threeNodesGraph);

}
```

When I try to run the tests, the compiler says:

```
tests/newtestclass1.h:36:5: error: ‘GraphPrinter’ does not name a type
     GraphPrinter printer;
     ^
tests/newtestclass1.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void newtestclass1::setUp()’:
tests/newtestclass1.cpp:52:5: error: ‘printer’ was not declared in this scope
     printer = GraphPrinter(threeNodesGraph);
     ^
tests/newtestclass1.cpp:52:43: error: ‘GraphPrinter’ was not declared in this scope
     printer = GraphPrinter(threeNodesGraph);
```

Normally, that would mean I have to forward declare GraphPrinter by including the headerfile.
But in another unit testing class I wrote, everything worked fine without including anything, but the boost namespace. I can call the constructor
of the class I want to test in setUp and have no issues.

I did some google research, but all I can find are errors which occur, because the constructor is not declared, or 'Class' is used instead of 'class', or the wrong headerfiles are included.

I believe the error is somehow connected to how CppUnit resolves namespaces, but I honestly don't know much about the way they work.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: did you include the header file for `GraphPrinter`?

Comment: I did now and it works I thought the #includes would be managed by netbeans itself, because I did not need to include any headers in my other testfile. Thank you very much!